# how to request a json file from an API using a list of lists instead of a list of values? how to speed up my API call?

Tags: python, pandas, api, asynchronous, geocoder

`geocoder.osm()` Is an API function that is supposed to take two arguments: latitude and longitude, and then it returns the country name and all of its informations as a json file.

I have a big dataframe of 700k rows full of coordinates i wrote the following code to extract every coordinate's Country name:

```
import geocoder
import itertools

count=itertools.count(start=0)

def geo_rev(x):
    print('starting: ',next(count))
    g = geocoder.osm([x.latitude, x.longitude], method='reverse').json
    try:
        if g:
            return [g.get('country'),g.get('city')]
        else:
            return ['no country','no city']
    except ValueError:
        pass
        

data[['Country','City']]=data[['latitude','longitude']].apply(geo_rev,axis=1,result_type='expand')
```

as you see we are passing a list of two values for every row: `[x.latitude, x.longitude]`.

**the problem is:** this code will take it forever to execute, that is why I want to pass a list of lists for the function `geocoder.osm()` to make the request even faster, my idea is to perform the following code:`[list[latitude...],list[longitude...] ]`, how to do it?

> TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'

But if my idea (about passing a list of lists) is wrong, if there are another way to make an API call faster please tell me.

Comment: If an API specifies that it wants a 2-list as input, that is what it wants. What you are apparently hoping for is that the function you are calling will simply understand, when your code passes it a list of 2-lists, that it is expected to loop through it and process each element in turn. It could of course be written to do that. But the message indicates that it hasn't been. Your only option is to make this a feature request to the `geocoder` support team.

Comment: isn't there a way to do it using `async` library?

Comment: Probably, but that is not what you asked. Your question was *How do I pass a list of coordinates to this function?* and not *How do I make multiple calls to this function in parallel to speed up execution?* That is a reasonable approach but it doesn't make the individual API calls any faster, which is what your question asked for.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have found an answer to my question, it looks very hard to do it using list of lists then i tried using **Threading** , Threading executes for APIs like asyncio at very high speed `probably even ten times or twenty times faster` it doesn't wait for every request to receive its file but it sends couple of requests at the same time, and then it receive thier files at the same time, the following code will worked right:

```
import geocoder
import itertools
import concurrent.futures

lst=list(zip(data.latitude.tolist(), data.longitude.tolist())) 
countries=[]
count=itertools.count(start=0)

def geo_rev(x):
    print('starting: ',next(count))
    g = geocoder.osm([x[0], x[1]], method='reverse').json
    
    try:
        if g:
            return g.get('country')
        else:
            return 'no country'
    except ValueError:
        pass
        
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    results=executor.map(geo_rev, lst)
    for result in results:
        countries.append(result)

data['Country']=[x for x in countries]
```

Thanks for Corey Schafer for his [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IEEhzQoKtQU&t=1476s) it explains everything.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is the question, but if you need to try getting the elements of the list, try to use "for i in list_name", it will get the elements one by one. If you need the elements of both lists, try "for i in range(len(list_name)):    function(list_name[0][i],list_name[1][i])"

Comment: sorry, not that one

Comment: I edited it, maybe now it's what you meant?

Comment: it have nothing to do with python it is about APIs

Comment: Wellcome to stackoverflow, please write answer to questions and topics that you understand , and please provide full solution to the problem

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).